# Distinguish between server-side errors and connection problems

Tags: codenameone

As described in the Codename One blog post "[Terse Table, Radar Chart and Networking Enhancements](https://www.codenameone.com/blog/terse-table-radar-chart-networking.html)":

> **Better Error Code Handling**
>
> Up until recently if we got an error response code it wasn’t sent
>   through the global error handler and was handled via the local error
>   handling chain first. This is no longer the case and these errors are
>   now handled correctly.
>
> However, if you relied on that misbehavior of older versions we have
>   `setHandleErrorCodesInGlobalErrorHandler(boolean)`. This defaults to
>   true, you can set it to false to change the default behavior.

So, the global error handler is invoked both by server-side errors and connection problems. It's a very good thing to be able to manage networks errors in the most generic way, however I need to distinguish between server-side errors and connection problems.

After some testing, I wrote the following code, tested on Simulator, Android and iOS:

```
addNetworkErrorListener(err -> {
            // prevents the event from propagating
            err.consume();

            if (err.getError() != null) {
                // this is the case of a network error,
                // like: java.io.IOException: Unreachable
                Log.p("Error connectiong to: " + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl());
                // maybe there are connectivity issues, let's try again
                ToastBar.showInfoMessage("Trying to reconnect...");
                Timer timer = new Timer();
                timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        err.getConnectionRequest().retry();
                    }
                }, 2000);
            } else {
                // this is the case of a server error
                // logs the error
                Log.p("REST ERROR\nURL:" + err.getConnectionRequest().getUrl()
                        + "\nMethod: " + err.getConnectionRequest().getHttpMethod()
                        + "\nRequest body: " + err.getConnectionRequest().getRequestBody()
                        + "\nResponse code: " + err.getConnectionRequest().getResponseCode()
                        + "\nResponse message: " + StringUtilities.toString(err.getConnectionRequest().getResponseData()),
                        Log.ERROR);

                Log.sendLogAsync();
                ToastBar.showErrorMessage("Server Error", 10000);
            }
        });
```

In the tested platforms, server-side errors are reported, but no further action follows; connectivity errors are both reported and managed by retrying the connection every two seconds.

So, that code works.

Anyway, what I don't like is the assumption that `err.getError() != null` is true for connectivity errors, false for server-side errors. I came to this assumption after several tests, but I didn't find it documented anywhere.

So my question is whether:

1. my assumption is always correct;
2. there is a better way to distinguish server-side errors from connectivity errors.

Thank you

Comment: Maybe we should have a subclass of NetworkEvent to indicate connectivity issues. Right now I'm unaware of a better approach