# ConnectionRequest pause() and resume()

Tags: codenameone

Are `ConnectionRequest` methods named `pause()` and `resume()` really implemented?

Looking at the sources, I imagined that they are "fake", in the sense they actually do nothing, except setting an internal flag:
https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/ConnectionRequest.java

So, my question is if Codename One offers any way to pause and then resume a large download (for example 10MB or 100MB, that could be the size of a video). My idea is to pause the download when the app goes to background and then resume it when the app returns to foreground, **without re-downloading the already downloaded data**: this could circumvent the issue described in my previous question: [How to improve the behavior of ConnectionRequest?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62093943/how-to-improve-the-behavior-of-connectionrequest)

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like they are implemented but notice you need to override `isPausable()` to return true which currently no `ConnectionRequest` does.

It might make sense to add a `setDefaultPausable(boolean)` method to `ConnectionRequest` to make this usage easier and more universal e.g. with the `Rest` API.

Comment: Unfortunately the overidde of `isPausable()` has no effect: the `pause()` and `resume()` methods do nothing when downloading a file to Storage (tested on Simulator, Android and iOS).

Comment: Looking at the Codename One sources, it seems that `currentRequest.isPausable()` is used only by the `NetWorkManager`, when the priority `ConnectionRequest.PRIORITY_CRITICAL` is set (I refer to the line 842 of https://github.com/codenameone/CodenameOne/blob/master/CodenameOne/src/com/codename1/io/NetworkManager.java). So it's not meant to be used by the developer to pause and resume a partial download. It's for a different internal use, if I understood correctly.

Comment: That's in order to invoke `pause` if you add a critical request. You're right that it pausability isn't required. But using `pause()` / `resume()` should work since they use a similar API to kill.