# How to enable Background Fetch for iOS in Codename One

Tags: codenameone, background-fetch

The original documentation of the [Codename One BackgroundFetch interface](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/background/BackgroundFetch.html) says: *"include **fetch** in the ios.background_modes build hint"*. The build hints can be found in the Codename One simulator in the "Tools" menu. So I entered **fetch** in this field and saved. This will be written into file /appname-common/codenameone_settings.properties as
`codename1.arg.ios.background_modes=fetch`

But it has no effect. Method
`public void performBackgroundFetch(final long deadline, final Callback<Boolean> onComplete)`
in class MyApp of my iOS enterprise app will never be called by iOS while the app is sleeping in background. My code is the same as in various examples I have found. Method **start()** in main class MyApp (which extends Lifecycle) includes

```
Display.getInstance().setPreferredBackgroundFetchInterval(300);
if (Display.getInstance().isBackgroundFetchSupported()) {
    log.p("Background fetching is supported");
}
```

Whenever I bring my app to front, it starts again with

```
[EDT] 0:0:0,167 - MyApp.start()
[EDT] 0:0:0,176 - Background fetching is supported
[EDT] 0:0:0,176 - MyApp.runApp()
etc.
```

What have I done wrong? What's missing?

Codename One 7.0.108
Apple iPhone 14 Pro
Apple iOS 16.5.1

Comment: Did you look at the [thread here](https://groups.google.com/g/codenameone-discussions/c/Q4pwB28AG5I/m/tIsWgnOBDAAJ?pli=1)?
Also check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62137379/756809).